# How to Check if Div exists on Current Page

Tags: javascript

I want to check if div exists on current page. I tried below condition, but it always goes through `div.value` even I check if `div` is `undefined` before going into `div.value`.

How exactly can I check whether or not div exists on current page?

```js
var div = document.getElementById("id");
var id = div !== "undefined" ? div.value : null;
```

Comment: `var id = div ? div.value : null;`

Comment: Divs don't have values, inputs do.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById("id");
var id = div ? div.value : null;
```

If div does not exist, it will be `undefined`, not `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 0):

> How exactly can I check whether or not div exists on current page?

**Using if statement**

```
if (document.getElementById("id")) {
    // does exist
}else{
   // does NOT exist
}
```

**Using ternary operator**

```
var div = document.getElementById("id");
var id = div ? div.value : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple condition. If there's no a div with given `id`, it will return `null`.

```js
function checkDiv(id) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id),
      res = !!div;
      console.log(`#${id} - ${res}`);
}

checkDiv('bla');
checkDiv('a');
```

```html
<div id='a'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not a property of `div` use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("id");
var id = div !== "undefined" ? div.innerHTML : null;
console.log(id);;
```

```html
<div id="id">ABC</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
var div = document.querySelector('#id');
```

which will return null if no element with that id is found.